# how we will find camera is running or not in any application?

Tags: android

***How we will find Camera is open or not in any application?***
=>i have one service in our application where camera is going on continue on in background,but now i am open again default camera application at that time camera not found exception occur.

=>At that time i want to any notification if camera is open in other application. if any body have idea than please give me suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have one service in our application where camera is going on continue on in background

This is not supported by Android AFAIK.

> At that time i want to any notification if camera is open in other application

This is not supported by Android AFAIK.